# JQuery active class based on url not working as expected

Tags: jquery

I'm at a loss for why the following logic isn't working as expected. I would like to remove any active classes on click and then add the class back to only the li with an href that corresponds to the url.

```
var str=location.href.toLowerCase();
  $(".navlinks li a").each(function() {
  if (str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
   $("li.active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  }
 });

<ul class="navlinks">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      <li><a href="/give">Give</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="/volunteer">Volunteer</a></li>
      <li><a href="/events">Calendar</a></li>
      <li><a href="/services">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Currently a blank class is being attached to each li on click.

Comment: it seems like the problem is with the removeClass. The addclass works fine with that line commented out. It seems like the remove class is called after the addClass for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this inside if statement:

```
 $("li.active").removeAttribute("class");
 $(this).parent().addClass("active");
```

For me it works.

Edit: put this outside:

```
    Var isexecutedonce = false;
```

And inside foreach loop write:

```
   If(!isexecutedonce){
   $("li.active").removeAttribute("class");
   Isexecutedonce = true;
   }
```

This outside if:

```
     $(this).parent().addClass("active");
```

Comment: It doesn't work for some reason. Instead of the li elements receiving an empty class they don't receive one at all. It's almost like the removeAttribute is getting called after the addClass.

Comment: I get it now. It happens because for loop is executed again and again and that is why it doesn't work. I will update answer.